# SilverStripe: Forbidden Permission Error

Tags: php, centos, silverstripe

I've created a site using SilverStripe. It's working on my wamp server and it's working on a shared server - however, when  I configured it on Cent OS apache (`/var/www/html/info`)  it says:

```
Forbidden

You don't have permission to access /info on this server.
```

I have changed the `httpd.conf` file as [this post](http://www.silverstripe.org/community/forums/installing-silverstripe/show/12256) suggests, but it's still not working.

Comment: is the rewrite engine enabled ? refer here to test it http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html

Comment: Did you deploy the .htaccess file where all the rewrite rules are defined?
Can the web server user read the files?

Comment: Please switch to dev mode and see if it's a php error or a webserver configuration error. Did you have a look in the error logs (apache and silverstripe) ?

Comment: sking Yes its enabled,  
wmk yes its 777 ,  
   
I run   
restorecon -r /var/www/html  
on terminal, then Forbidden Permission Error gone. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

On Cent OS terminal Run

```
restorecon -r /var/www/html
```

then Forbidden Permission Error gone.